# Elements of a class aggregate

Tags: c++, aggregate-initialization

I am trying to understand the changes that happened from C++14 to C++17 regarding aggregate initialization. From [§9.4.2[dcl.init.aggr]/2](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#2):

> The elements of an aggregate are:
>
> - (2.1) for an array, the array
>   elements in increasing subscript order, or
> - (2.2) **for a class, the
>   direct base classes in declaration order, followed by the direct
>   non-static data members ([class.mem]) that are not members of an
>   anonymous union, in declaration order.**

This paragraph defines what the elements of an aggregate class are. In particular, I can't get what the bold sentence means. I have this example to demonstrate my confusion:

```
struct Base { int mem1, mem2; }; 
struct Derived : Base { int mem3, mem4; };

Derived obj = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
```

The object `obj` is an aggregate since it satisfies the criteria defined in [[dcl.init.aggr]/1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#1). My problem, however, is what are the elements of this aggregate. It seems that the elements are `Base::mem1` initialized with 1, `Base::mem2` initialized with 2, `Derived::mem3` initialized with 3, and `Dervied::mem4` initialized with 4.

But [dcl.init.aggr]/2 states the opposite. It is said that the elements are the data members of the direct base classes, which is `Base` in this case, **followed** by the direct non-static data members of the `Derived` class. Am I parsed the wording correctly?.

I really don't know whether or not I understood the quote correctly, but I think I don't. So any explanation regarding this point will help me alot.

Comment: Think of it like people waiting in a line. If Bob follows Alice, then Alice is earlier in the line and gets served first. Base is followed by derived. Base comes first and derived comes later, following base. Base gets 1 and 2, derived comes after and gets 3 and 4.

Comment: @user4581301. Does this what 2.2 bullet means?

Comment: For the first part that deals in base and derived and who comes first, yes. There is also the bit about anonymous `union`s and I don't know that stuff well enough to be comfortable commenting on it. I don't think I've ever used an anonymous `union` in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your understanding of the concept "elements of an aggregate" is correct. However, that's not the end of aggregate initialization. There is [brace elision](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.aggr#16):

> Braces can be elided in an initializer-list as follows. If the initializer-list begins with a left brace, then the succeeding comma-separated list of initializer-clauses initializes the elements of a subaggregate; it is erroneous for there to be more initializer-clauses than elements. If, however, the initializer-list for a subaggregate does not begin with a left brace, then only enough initializer-clauses from the list are taken to initialize the elements of the subaggregate; any remaining initializer-clauses are left to initialize the next element of the aggregate of which the current subaggregate is an element.
>
> All implicit type conversions ([conv]) are considered when initializing the element with an assignment-expression. If the assignment-expression can initialize an element, the element is initialized. Otherwise, if the element is itself a subaggregate, brace elision is assumed and the assignment-expression is considered for the initialization of the first element of the subaggregate.

Since `Base b = 1;` is not a valid initialization statement, brace elision is assumed, as defined in the first paragraph.